# Snakemake: specifying a workdir in YAML config file

Tags: config, snakemake

I specified a workdir in the YAML config file to use with snakemake as follows:

```
$> cat config.yaml
workdir: "/home/lina/test_output"
id: 1234

$> cat Snakefile
rule all:
  input:
    data_out = expand("cat_out/{id}_times_two.txt", id = config['id'])

rule double_print:
  input:
    data = expand("data/{id}.txt", id = config['id'])
  output:
    data_out = expand("cat_out/{id}_times_two.txt", id = config['id'])
  shell:
    'cat {input.data} {input.data} > {output.data_out}'

$> snakemake --configfile=config.yaml
```

However, once I ran my snakemake command, the output was generated in the directory where the snakefile resides. My snakefile was able to take advantage of the `id` parameter I specified in the config file, so it was able to read the config file and at least interpret the `id` parameter.

How should I modify the config file or my snakemake command to make sure the output ends up in the `workdir` I specified?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [add `workdir` to the snakefile](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#configure-working-directory), not the configuration.

But you can set it dynamically, so in the snakefile, write:

```
workdir: config['workdir']
```

Comment: Thank you, it works if I specify `workdir` in the Snakefile. However, it only seems to work if I hard code the path.

Could you show an example of a case where the `workdir` can be dynamically defined (i.e. in the config file)?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to do it in the config file. The docs do say, though, that setting it via the command line is preferred. Maybe that’s the better option, if you can manage it.

Comment: I saw this in the documentation:

"Usually, it is preferred to only set the working directory via the command line, because above directive limits the portability of Snakemake workflows."

I am running snakemake version 4.8.0 but there doesn't seem to be a command line option to set the `workdir`. Maybe the best practices approach is to manually change into the `workdir` using `cd` before running snakemake.

Comment: I take it back. I got this to work: 

In the `config.yaml` file set `outdir: "/path/to/workdir"`

In the `Snakefile`, specify `workdir: config['outdir']`

Comment: Ah, I see! Great.

Comment: `config` values can be set via the command line using `--config workdir=path/to/workdir/` (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#standard-configuration).